# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: laravel

Iam trying to update a specific data using post method. After submitting the form it shows an error : The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

editpage.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <h3>Update Book</h3>
    <br>
    <form action="update" method="post"  >

        {{csrf_field()}}

        @foreach($array as $fetch)

        <div><input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$fetch->id}}"></div>
        <div><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control " placeholder="Bookname" value="{{$fetch->name}}" ></div><br>


        <div><textarea name="content" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Description" >{{$fetch->content}}</textarea></div><br>

        <div><input type="text" name="author" class="form-control" placeholder="Author" value="{{$fetch->author}}"></div> <br>

        <div><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Book" class="btn btn-success" ></div>
        @endforeach
    </form>
</div>

@endsection
```

Web Route

````````
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/addbook',function () {
    return view('AddBook');
});

Route::post('/insert',['uses'=>'BookController@insert']);
Route::get('/delete/{id}',['uses'=>'BookController@delete']);
Route::get('/edit/{id}',['uses'=>'BookController@edit']);

``````
Route::post('/update',['uses'=>'BookController@update']);

```````

Route::get('/home',['uses'=>'BookController@index']);

Auth::routes();
````````

Comment: `<form action="/update">`

Comment: @UkraineInMembrane is correct, without the leading forward slash the action is appended to the current url.

Answer (score 1):

There are action  like update which requires the method submitted to the server url to be either PUT/PATCH (to modify the resource)

Try with this,

```
<form action="{{ route('book.update') }}" method="post"  >
    {{csrf_field()}}
    {{ method_field('PUT') }}

    @foreach($array as $fetch)
       // ...
    @endforeach
</form>
```

Your Route,

```
Route::put('update',['uses'=>'BookController@update', 'as' => 'book.update']);
```

Your Controller

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    // ...
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: +1 for using the PUT method, though I think you should explain why you're using this method instead of POST.